# change DNS but keep email server

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, hosting

I currently have my client's website hosted in china and the domain is hosted in www.net.cn

I've purchased an inmotionhosting plan and i want to move the website there.

For having the website working i just need to change the DNS nameservers but i want to keep the email in the client's old server, is this possible?

Currently i have this DNS:

```
MX      mxn.mxhichina.com.  5
MX      mxw.mxhichina.com.  10
CNAME   pop3    pop3.mxhichina.com. --
CNAME   smtp    smtp.mxhichina.com. --
CNAME   mail    mail.mxhichina.com. --
CNAME   m   m.mxhichina.com.    --
TXT     v=spf1 include:spf.m... --
A   @   223.4.215.96    --
A   www 223.4.215.96    --
```

and in inmotionhosting i have this:

```
example.com.    14400   IN  A   216.194.168.46
localhost.example.com.  14400   IN  A   127.0.0.1
mail.example.com.   14400   IN  CNAME   example.com
www.example.com.    14400   IN  CNAME   example.com
webmail.example.com.    14400   IN  A   216.194.168.46
```

What do i have to change to have the website working on the new server but keeping the email server where it is right now?

Comment: You're talking about changing where your DNS service is hosted as well as where your web service is hosted at the same time.  This seems unnecessarily risky.  Why not do them separately?

Comment: do them separately? don't understand what you mean.Risky? why?

Comment: If you just change the two A records (`www` and `@`) in the old DNS server to the new IP address, your web visitors will start hitting the new web server.  No need to change who provides your DNS.  Doubling the number of things you are changing doubles the risk. (Roughly)

Comment: i'm going to do that, it seems to be the best option.Lets see if it works

Comment: This is the problem with web hosting companies getting involved in their clients DNS. They think they have to muck around with name servers and MX records. Presumably the client has one or more A records for the web site, if you're moving only the web site then change the applicable A records and leave everything else alone.

Comment: @ladadadada it worked.If you write that in an answer i'll mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just change the two A records (`www` and `@`) in the old DNS server to the new IP address, your web visitors will start hitting the new web server. No need to change who provides your DNS.

Doubling the number of things you are changing doubles the risk of something going wrong. (Roughly)

Answer (score 0):

Add the MX record inmotionhosting and point to www.net.cn as you have there

MX      mxn.mxhichina.com.  5
MX      mxw.mxhichina.com.  10

Why do you want to add the following records in inmotionhosting? I understood that your mail server should remain in China. 
mail.example.com.   14400   IN  CNAME   example.com
webmail.example.com.    14400   IN  A   216.194.168.46

Comment: the inmotionhosting records have been automatically generated by inmotion, i haven't added them. So i just have to change the nameservers for web and add MX mxn.mxhichina.com. 5 MX mxw.mxhichina.com. 10 to inmotion?

Comment: maybe i can change just the A www 223.4.215.96 to add the inmotion ip and then the website would be working in the new hosting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to change the DNS record on your CP. Please kindly point your A record to immotion Ip address.